# How to create a QML map standalone runnable with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyinstaller, pyside2

I have a dummy python program which creates a Qt widget app with a QML map as a main widget (QQuickWidget).

The code works fine if I run the source code (`python main.py`). The problem comes when I try to create a standalone runnable with pyinstaller. The runnable is generated correctly but when I run it the **map is empty** and the following message appears in the **console output**:

```sh
1 ,  "The geoservices provider is not supported."
```

I assume that the runnable is created well because if I change my `view.qml` with something even more dummy (removing the map) works fine. Btw, I'm generating it by:

```sh
pyinstaller --add-data "view.qml:." --onefile main.py
```

My **main.spec** is:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['/home/parias/Documentos/pyside_pruebas/wigdet-map'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('view.qml', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

I also add my source files in case I'm making a mistake in them:

**main.py**:

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, Slot, QUrl
from PySide2.QtQuickWidgets import QQuickWidget

import sys
import os


class MapWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MapWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.map_widget = QQuickWidget(self)
        url = QUrl("view.qml")

        self.map_widget.setSource(url)
        self.map_widget.setResizeMode(QQuickWidget.SizeRootObjectToView)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.map_widget)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.main_widget = MapWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**view.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtLocation 5.15
import QtPositioning 5.15
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Item {
    width: 512
    height: 512
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
        PluginParameter { name: "osm.useragent"; value: "Prueba" }
        PluginParameter { name: "osm.mapping.copyright"; value: "All mine" }
        PluginParameter { name: "osm.mapping.highdpi_tiles"; value: true }
    }

    Map {
        id: map_map
        objectName: "map"
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(40.091675, -3.696038) // Seseña
        zoomLevel: 14
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to copy the plugin that Map uses, for that you must follow the following procedure:

- Obtain the path of the plugin path by executing the following command in the console:

```
python -c "from PySide2.QtCore import QLibraryInfo; print(QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.PluginsPath))"
```

Output

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/plugins
```

- Copy the "plugins/geoservices" directory to the side of the executable

Output:

````
├── geoservices
│   ├── libqtgeoservices_esri.so
│   ├── libqtgeoservices_itemsoverlay.so
│   ├── libqtgeoservices_mapboxgl.so
│   ├── libqtgeoservices_mapbox.so
│   ├── libqtgeoservices_nokia.so
│   └── libqtgeoservices_osm.so
├── main
└── view.qml
```
````

Comment: Thanks! You're awesome!